# How do I formulate this linear programming problem? (especially the second restriction)

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

> A factory creates different types of oils and mixes them together. There exists two types of vegetarian oils (veg1,veg2) and three types of non-vegetarian oils (oil1,oil2,oil3), the price of each oil (per ton) is: 
>  veg1=$115$, veg2=$128$, oil1=$132$, oil2=$109$, oil3=$114$. 
>  The final product is a mix of these oils and is sold for $180$ dollars for each ton. The goal is to maximize the profit of the factory, under the following restrictions:
>
> 1. We can't refine more than $210$ tons of vegetarian oil, and more than $260$ tons of non vegetarian oil.
> 2. There exists a restrictment on the viscosities (from google translate, hope it makes sense) of the final product, it can't be lower than $3.5$ and not higher than $6.2$. We assume that the oils are mixed in a linear manner and the viscosity of each oil is: 
>    veg1=$8.8$, veg2=$6.2$, oil1=$1.9$, oil2=$4.3$, oil3=$5.1$

---

**Note:** The main part of my question is understanding the second restriction. Here's my work until I reached that:
Decision Variables: 
let $x_1,x_2$ be the amount in tons that we bought from veg1 and veg2 oils. 
$y_1,y_2,y_3$ the amount in tons that we bought from oil1,oil2 and oil3.


Our goal function should be the profit of the factory, and we need to maximize that. 
First, we need to know our product sales money, and that is $180$ for each ton of the mix, I got confused of how to express it, but I think the most intuitive way is $180*(x_1+x_2+y_1+y_2+y_3)$, since the mix is made from all the oils (and they didn't mention them needing to have the same proportions). 
Second, the cost of the oils which is $115x_1+128x_2+132y_1+109y_2+114y_3$. 
 
So Our function is: $180*(x_1+x_2+y_1+y_2+y_3)-115x_1+128x_2+132y_1+109y_2+114y_3$. 
From the first restriction, we get these inequalities: $x_1+x_2\le 210$ and $y_1+y_2+y_3\le 260$.
But here I got stuck, because I don't understand what that second restriction is, I'm not sure what they meant by linear manner here.

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com

Comment: Cross-posted: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7242/formulating-a-linear-programming-problem-with-indicator-variables-solution-ve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it means that the resulting viscosity will be a weighed average of the individual viscosities:
$$
Visc = \dfrac{8.8 x_1 + 6.2 x_2 + 1.9 y_1 + 4.3 y_2 + 5.1 y_3}{x_1+x_2+y_1+y_2+y_3}
$$

So, for instance, the restriction $Visc \leq 6.2$ would be equivalent  to
$$
\dfrac{8.8 x_1 + 6.2 x_2 + 1.9 y_1 + 4.3 y_2 + 5.1 y_3}{x_1+x_2+y_1+y_2+y_3}\leq 6.2\Leftrightarrow $$

$$8.8 x_1 + 6.2 x_2 + 1.9 y_1 + 4.3 y_2 + 5.1 y_3 \leq 6.2(x_1+x_2+y_1+y_2+y_3) \Leftrightarrow
$$

$$
2.6 x_1-4.3 y_1-1.9y_2-1.1y_3 \leq 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, but can you tell me what made you reach that this is what is meant in the question? (Like I would have never thought of weighed average, it fits good, but I would love to hear what's the thing that brought this idea). Thanks again

Comment: @Pwaol We have the individual viscosities, but the restriction is on the resulting viscosity. So, there must be a criteria for obtaining the viscosity of the mix from the viscosities of the components. Although the phrasing in the question is not very explicit, when they speak of linear mixing it seems they are saying the viscosity varies linearly when you add the components.

Comment: Sorry for the late question, but I've been thinking if the phrase "in a linear manner" usually imply weighed average? When I imagine something linear it's like $x_1+x_2-y_1$ ... or something, I can't reach the conclusion of why we could think of average

Comment: Or maybe just a sum of the variables linearly without an average (which seem not logical) but it's what I understand from the word "linear", i'm a little confused.

Comment: @Pawaol It does not make sense to consider just the sum... When you mix two fluids with the same viscosity you do not get a mixture with twice the viscosity.